# how can you make python to click on a pop up button to automatically open a file when you download it?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using selenium to try and automatically download a file each day.
I'm not able to get past this image though

[image]

I'm trying to use pyautogui to register where the "ok" button using this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.screenshot('C:\\Users\\file location of screenshot')
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:\\Users\\file location of screenshot of "ok" button')
```

Currently, I have a first screenshot of the whole message, and a second screenshot with the "ok" button where I want the click to happen.

However, because I have a blue light filter on my computer, the command doesn't to register the "ok" location on the computer and doesn't give me back coordinates of where the screenshot is on the screen.

Is there a way of automatically clicking  on the "ok" button that might not get blocked by the blue light filter? Or even a way to help the computer recognize the "ok" button even with the blue light filter on?

Thanks!

Comment: "*I have a blue light filter on my computer*" As in, physically on your screen? Can you provide more details on the "blue light filter" aspect? In either case, can you elaborate as to why you believe this would affect the functionality of `pyautogui` if both screenshots were taken with this same "filter" applied?

Comment: hello, yep I'm using f.lux to dim the blue light on my screen because it helps me looking at the screen. I tried taking a screenshot of the whole message, as well as the place where I wanted  `pyautogui` to click without the filter, and `pyautogui`  was able to give me the coordinates to click on.